# can not load Spring application context from tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have the next project structure:

```
src/
   main/
       java/
           DAO/Dao classes
           data/data classes
       resources/
           application-context.xml
    test/
        java/
            data/ Test files
        resources/
               application-context-test.xml
```

When I load context outside tests i use:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
```

and it works.And if use

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context.xml"})
```

inside tests - it works. But if I use for:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml"})
```

I got exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Any ideas why? Maybe something is wrong with XML file?

Comment: /tests must not be on your classpath.

Comment: Could you add a `/` at the beginning? `classpath:/application-context-test.xml`. This usually fixes similar issues.... and I think it's a good practice as it narrows where to find the resource.

Comment: Are you running your tests from  eclipse, maven, ant??

Comment: Yes. In eclipse. I use Spring, Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your main and test directories are set up as source directories in eclipse. You can do this from the ui, but you can also open the hidden .classpath file at the root of your application source. The beginning should look something like what you see before where the paths match your file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    .
    .
    .
</classpath>
```

If it does, the tests should work. If not they won't.

You can do this from the UI by right clicking on the src/main/resources  directory and selecting Build Path >> Add to Build Path. Your package explorer should look something like this with each of the source directories at the top.[image]